# Windows Firewall selects wrong profile after restart (PRIVATE / PUBLIC / DOMAIN)

Tags: windows, windows-firewall

At some servers we have the problem that after restart Windows Server selects a **PRIVATE** domain profile in stead of **DOMAIN**.

[image]

[image]

We can solve the problem by resetting the Network Adapater:

```
Restart-NetAdapter Ethernet0
```

Does anyone have a permanent solution?

We tried:

1. Run the Powershell script above a couple of minutes after boot (using Task Scheduler), but that somehow doesn't work.
2. Verified that the Domain Controller can be found using

> nltest /dsgetdc:domain.lan

3. Verified that DNS was able to find the domain-controllers:

> nslookup _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain.lan

I'm also aware of some registry-settings that can be modified (**NegativeCachePeriod**, **AlwaysExpectDomainControllert** and **AlwaysExpectDomainController**) as stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/400385/network-location-awareness-not-detecting-domain-ne.html but I didn't want to just try this in a production environment.

I have once reserved an entire evening to try a couple of suggestions on a production server with this issue and that evening I could restart the server multiple times without the problem happening at all. So it's difficult to replicate.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be solved with the follow registry-key:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NlaSvc\Parameters] "AlwaysExpectDomainController"=dword:00000001
```

More info on: https://server-essentials.com/support/windows-firewall-shows-public-or-private-profile-on-a-domain-controller